# Wordpress Plugins / Custom Class / get_option() / shortcode

Tags: plugins, wordpress

I'm having an issue displaying information returned from a custom class defined within a plugin's files, when using a shortcode. I'll write up some mock files that showcase my issue.

**/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/classes/my_class.php**

```
<?php
class People {
  public $api_url = "https://www.external-service.com/api";
  private $api_key;

  function __construct($key = null) {
    if $(key) {
      $this->api_key = $key;
    }

  function get_response() {
    $path = $this->api_url . "?my_api_token=" . $this->api_key;
  }
}
?>
```

**/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/my-plugin.php**

```
<?php
/**
* all of the wordpress plugin comments
* ...
*/

require "myplg_options.php";
require "myplg_shortcodes.php";
```

The options page and menu is generated from myplg_options; it is functioning correctly (including using get_option to retrieve the saved option (in this case, the api key).

**/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/myplg_shortcodes.php**

```
<?php
require "classes/my_class.php";

$options = get_option('myplg_settings');
$myplg = new People($options['myplg_api_key']);
$response = $myplg->get_response();

function myplg_list_result(){
  echo "the shortcode is working!";
  var_dump($options, $myplg, $respnose);
}
add_shortcode('myplg_list', 'myplg_list_result');
?>
```

Testing externally from wordpress, the class works and everything is fine and dandy. The plugin's option page sets and retains the single option perfectly; the shortcode actually registers and is usable from within a WordPress page/portfolio/etc.

The issue I'm having is that using `var_dump`, ***all three*** of those variables are dumped as `NULL`.

After doing some homework, I was able to determine that moving the three variable declarations *inside* the shortcode makes it work. It would seem to me, however, that doing that is not the best workflow, as I'd need to re-grab the option, instantiate a new class, and call the class' function for every shortcode.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: It's because of the [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). You should add `global $options, $myplg, $respnose;` at the top of `myplg_list_result()`, but it's not safe to use global variables because they can be changed anywhere from any script. If you don't want to re-instantiate maybe use a [singleton class](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html#singleton).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment it's because variables are function scoped. You may be better off using a Closure.

```
<?php
require "classes/my_class.php";

$options = get_option('myplg_settings');
$myplg = new People($options['myplg_api_key']);
$response = $myplg->get_response();
add_shortcode('myplg_list', function() use ($options, $response, $myplg) {
    echo "the shortcode is working!";
    var_dump($options, $myplg, $respnose);
});
```